# determine if the span of the vectors are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do I determine if the vector span $(u_1,u_2)$ is equal to the vector span of $(v_1,v_2)$ in $\Bbb R^6$? In other words, how do I show that $\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2) = \operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$:

\begin{align}
u_1&=(1,0,1,0,1,0) \\
u_2&=(0,1,1,1,1,-1) \\ \\
v_1&=(4,-5,-1,-5,-1,5) \\
v_2&=(-3,2,-1,2,-1,-2)
\end{align}

I don't know how i determine this. I have tried setting them equal to each other and getting them to reduced row-echelon form, but I do not know if that is correct.

Comment: Express $v_1$ and $v_2$ as linear combinations of $u_1,u_2$. This will prove that the plane $\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$ is a subspace of the plane $\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2)$, hence they are equal.

Comment: The description of your attempts is unclear and not explicit enough.

Comment: What i tried to do was write u1, u2, v1 and v2 as an augmented matrix with u1, and u2 being the coefficient matrix and v1 and v2 being the "b" as in [A l b], i then tried reaching a rref form from there. I also tried multiplying a diffrent koeficient into into the vectors so i got a*u1, b*u2, c*v1, d*v2. From there i tried writing u1 as a combination of v1 and v2, u2 as a combination of v1 and v2, and then the same for v1 and v2 just using u1 and u2

Comment: Much better! But instead of this comment, it would be still better to include explicitely your calculations in your post, so that we can see where you were stuck.

Answer (score 8):

As the sets $\{u_{1},u_{2}\}$ and $\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ are linearly independent (This means that both sets have rank 2.), proving that the matrix below has rank 2 implies that any vector in $\text{span}\{u_{1},u_{2}\}$ is in $\text{span}\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ and vice versa, because otherwise the rank would increase to 3 or 4.

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
-u_{1}-\\
-u_{2}-\\
-v_{1}-\\
-v_{1}-
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
4 & -5 & -1 & -5 & -1 & 5\\
-3 & 2 & -1 & 2 & -1 & -2
\end{array}\right)\longrightarrow\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & -5 & -5 & -5 & -5 & 5\\
0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & -2
\end{array}\right)\longrightarrow\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right)\longrightarrow\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
\boxed{1} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & \boxed{1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right).
$$

At the end, we obtained two linearly independent rows, so the rank of the original matrix is 2, as we were looking for.

In general, given $U=\{u_{1},\dots,u_{k}\}$ and $V=\{v_{1},\dots,v_{l}\}$ sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we have:

$$
\text{rank}(U)=\text{rank}(V)=\text{rank}\left(\begin{array}{c}
U\\
V
\end{array}\right) \iff \text{span}(U)=\text{span}(V).
$$

Comment: how did you figure out they were linearly independant

Comment: $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ are linearly independent because $u_{1}$ has a zero in component 2, and no multiple of it will give a 1 in that component, as $u_{2}$ does.

On the other hand, the third component of $v_{1}$ has a -1, just like $v_{2}$. Therefore, neither can be a multiple of the other because the rest of the components are not all equal.

Comment: thank you for the help i appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

To prove that $\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2) = \operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$, you have to show that $\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2)\subseteq \operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$ and $\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)\subseteq\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2)$.

Let $x\in\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2)$ be arbitrary, then
$$x=\alpha u_1+\beta u_2,$$
where $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$. Since
$$u_1=-\frac{2}{7}v_1-\frac{5}{7}v_2 \ \text{and} \ u_2=-\frac{3}{7}v_1-\frac{4}{7}v_2,$$
it follows that
$$x=-\frac{1}{7}(2\alpha+3\beta)v_1-\frac{1}{7}(5\alpha+4\beta)v_2.$$
This means that $x\in\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$ for all $x$. Therefore, we have $\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2)\subseteq \operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$.

I will leave it up to you to prove that $\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)\subseteq\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2)$.

Comment: thank you for the help i appreciate it

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: How did you guess the -2/7, -5/7, -3/7 and -4/7?

Comment: For example, you suppose 
$$u_1=xv_1+yv_2,$$
then you substitute $u_1=(1,0,1,0,1,0), \  v_1=(4,-5,-1,-5,-1,5)$, and $v_2=(-3,2,-1,2,-1,-2)$ into the equation above to get
$$(1,0,1,0,1,0)=(4x-3y,-5x+2y,-x-y,-5x+2y,-x-y,5x-2y)$$
From this you obtain a system of linear equations whose solution is $x=-\frac{2}{7}$ and $y=-\frac{5}{7}$. Therefore,
$$u_1=-\frac{2}{7}v_1-\frac{5}{7}v_2,$$

Comment: using your method i arrived at v1 = 4u1-5u2, v2 = -3u1+2u2. I arrived at this by putting it into an augmented matrix and placeing [ x*u1 + y*u2 l v1] and  [ x*u1 + y*u2 l v2] and reaching the reduced row-echolon form. so since they are possible write as a linear combination they must span the same space and therefore span(u1,u2) = span(v1,v2)?

Comment: I do not know. What I do know is that $\text{span}(u_1,u_2)$ and $\text{span}(v_1,v_2)$ are sets. Thus, $\text{span}(u_1,u_2)=\text{span}(v_1,v_2)$ means that $\text{span}(u_1,u_2)\subseteq \text{span}(v_1,v_2)$ and $\text{span}(v_1,v_2)\subseteq\text{span}(u_1,u_2)$. I have already proved in my answer that $\text{span}(u_1,u_2)\subseteq \text{span}(v_1,v_2)$. Now, you have to use the facts $v_1=4u_1-5u_2$ and $v_2=-3u_1+2u_2$ to prove that $\text{span}(v_1,v_2)\subseteq\text{span}(u_1,u_2)$. After that, you can finally conclude that $\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2)=\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$.